# How to test the existence of a file in a webform email twig template

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a webform with a Document File field. In my twig email template, I want to test if that field is empty. For text area fields for example, this syntax works :

`{% if webform_token('[webform_submission:values:question_text_area:value]', webform_submission) %}
 <br>
 <table>
  <tr>
  <th>Questions</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>{{ webform_token('[webform_submission:values:question_text_area:value]', webform_submission) }}</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 {% endif %}`

But for a Document File field, the same syntax does not work, meaning that if no file is uploaded, that part of my template is still printed.

I tried

`{% if webform_token('[webform_submission:values:join_a_file:value]', webform_submission) %}`

or

`{% if webform_token('[webform_submission:values:join_a_file:value]', webform_submission) is not null %}`

or

`{% if webform_token('[webform_submission:values:join_a_file]', webform_submission) is not null %}`

and none of them work.

Does anybody know the proper syntax for what I'm trying to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to do this

`{% if webform_token('[webform_submission:values:file:clear]', webform_submission) %}
  FILE UPLOADED
{% else %}
  NO FILE UPLOADED
{% endif %}`

Solution given first here : https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2969437